# Convert Pitch/Roll/Yaw vector, to Cartesian Components or Spherical Coordinates

Tags: vector-spaces, polar-coordinates

I'm given a magnitude and three angles of body rotation (pitch, roll, yaw), which form a vector v.

How do I find the cartesian components of v (x, y, z)?  How about converting v to the spherical coordinate system (r, θ, φ)?  Either or both would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations

Comment: @JG123 I looked at this, there are no conversions between pitch roll yaw vectors and anything else.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles